# pandas with pyodbc - Nan error: [42S22] ERROR: Attribute 'QNAN' not found (31) (SQLExecDirectW)

Tags: pandas, odbc, pyodbc

While running pyodbc execute() with data from pandas DataFrame (x1 is number type)

```
sql = "select * from t where x1=?"
cursor.execute(sql, df[row,'x1'])
```

got strange looking error:

**('42S22', "[42S22] ERROR: Attribute 'QNAN' not found (31) (SQLExecDirectW)")**

How to read the error message like that?

Answer (score 0):

Took me a while to put pieces together.
Here is how to read the error:

1. pyodbc expects x1 number but got Nan and translates it to string value 'QNAN'
2. sql became "select * from t where x1=QNAN"
3. parsing sql request by ODBC bridge [SQLExecDirect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms713611.aspx) function returns error status 42S22
4. **42S22** - [ODBC bridge error code](http://www.easysoft.com/developer/interfaces/odbc/sqlstate_status_return_codes.html) for "invalid column name"

Note, don't confuse pyodbc with ODBC bridge software. ODBC bridge is installed as part of your OS packages.